# Array to string angular

Tags: angularjs

New to angular. Please excuse me if this is a very simple question.

Is there anyway to convert array to string. 
My controller her the code:

```
$scope.addRow = function addRow(){     
    $scope.filters.push({ 'Name':$scope.name, 'dept': $scope.dept, 'city':$scope.city});
    $scope.name='';
    $scope.dept='';
    $scope.city='';
};
```

Now, I want to sent this data to a service as a string

I want it in the format "name,dept,city;name,dept,city". Is there any way to do it?

Service code looks like this:

```
                $scope.submit = function() {
                   myService.submit({
                      filters :$scope.filters
                 }, function(response) {
                    $scope.response = response; 
                });     
            };
```

I want to pass the value to filters in format "name,dept,city;name,dept,city" from the array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no need to do it, javascript sends data as Json when you do ajax calls

Comment: it sends it as unidentified. and I want to send it in the format "name,dept,city;name,dept,city"

Comment: So, you're asking how to do a string concatenation in javascript? ``var myString = stringA + "," + stringB;``

Comment: Editied question again. added more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
angular.toJson(array);
```

to create a json String of your array.

Edit:

```js
var array = [{name: 'misko', dept: '007', city: 'new york' }, {name: 'misko', dept: '007',city: 'new york'}];

function createStringByArray(array) {
    var output = '';
    angular.forEach(array, function (object) {
        angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
            output += key + ',';
            output += value + ',';
        });
    });
    return output;
}

var string = createStringFromArray(array);
```