# Convert array to string in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Im trying to convert an array of Strings, to a single string. I made a quick plunker of what I need in basic terms:

https://plnkr.co/edit/t2KeZJ8yOtDo2KxDQuzD?p=preview

In the app Im working on I need to use two different controllers and I created a factory for the controllers to share data, so I set the example up like that.

Here is the function I am trying to use to loop the array and add to a scope variable, with CherryPick being the array:

```
cherryCtrl.CherryPick = CherryPick.list;
cherryCtrl.string = cherryCtrl.output;


cherryCtrl.runString = function createString(array) {

    angular.forEach(cherryCtrl.CherryPick, function (object) {
        angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
            cherryCtrl.output += value + '  ';

            console.log(cherryCtrl.output);
        });
    });
    return cherryCtrl.output;

}
```

the console for output gives:

```
undefinedHello World  
undefinedHello World  object:5  
undefinedHello World  object:5  Goodbye World  
undefinedHello World  object:5  Goodbye World  object:8
```

Which is confusing.

I took the idea for the loop from here:

[Array to string angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435540/array-to-string-angular)

Any pointer would be mucho appreciated

Comment: there is no value assigned to `cherryCtrl.output`

Comment: What does the data in `cherryCtrl.CherryPick` look like?

Comment: What's confusing about that output?

Comment: The "undefined" at the beginning, presumably.   Initialize `cherryCtrl.output` with an empty string before you start using `+=` on it.

Comment: Why not just `array.join(' ')`?

Comment: The data in cherryCtrl.CherryPick looks like
    {"snippet":"Hello World"}

Comment: this interesting but `array.push({name})` add to array object {name: "namevalue"}` so seems you need simple `CherryPick.list.push(snippet)`

Comment: @Grundy that makes sense too, thanks

Comment: can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, because this work wrong for array of objects

Comment: @grundy I changed

   CherryPick.list.push(snippet ); 

And the loop a little and got what I was looking for working Thanks.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/t2KeZJ8yOtDo2KxDQuzD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, main problem with this code

```
CherryPick.list.push({
    snippet
});
```

In old browser not implement ES6 this code raise exception: `Syntax Error`, but in new standard this

```
{ snippet }
```

is [Shorthand property names (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), so you push to list not a *string* but *object* - `{snippet: "snippetvalue"}`.

After binding to view, in object added special angular property *$$hashKey* with value like *object:5*, that's why you see unexpected string in output.

For solution you can add string instead object,

```
CherryPick.list.push(// NOTE: without curly brackets
    snippet
);
```